# Plotting numeric frequency data based on midpoints of bins in base R or ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram, density-plot

I am replicating simulation results from a published study.  The authors present their output in a density plot (below) that is very rectangular.  They appear to have created bins and then plotted the midpoint of the bins.  Is it possible to easily build this type of plot using **base R** graphics or **ggplot**?

[image]

Comment: No data or code is difficult to do anything, just say "certainly possible".

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple indeed:

```
data=rnorm(1000)
hist_info=hist(data, plot=F)
plot(hist_info$mids, hist_info$density, type="l", xlab="X", ylab="density")
```

[image]